# How to store object in redux react (Open Weather API data)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I want to store an object in redux but it's giving the error--->

> Unhandled Rejection (Error): Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {coord, weather, base, main, visibility, wind, clouds, dt, sys, timezone, id, name, cod}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

It's saving the data but it not rendering it is showing the above error.
Can you please help me to store the object?

code

```
dispatch(weather(data)); //storing the object
```

```
//action
export const weather = (t) =>{
    return({
        type: 'Change',
        payload: t,
    });
}
```

```
//reducers
const weather = (state = null, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "Change_weather":
            return state = action.payload;
        
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
export default weather;
```

Comment: can you please share you code ?

Comment: @iskandar47, shared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change your action type to:

```
//action
export const weather = (t) =>{
    return({
        type: 'Change_weather',
        payload: t,
    });
}
```

Because if you keep your action type `Change` there is no case define in your reducer to handle `Change` type. And your store's initial value is `null`

Comment: While creating action type use `CHANGE_WEATHER` instead of `Change_weather`. It's good practice.